# Cannot set property 'age' of undefined

Tags: angular

this is my model class and i am trying to set the value in my component but i am getting error that "Cannot set property 'age' of undefined"....

frst.model.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';


    export interface mydata
    {
    name :string;
    age:string;
    data: string;
    }
```

fsrt-Component.ts

```
import { Component,Output,Input,OnInit, } from '@angular/core';
import { mydata } from './frst.model';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-Component',
  template: `
  <div><h1>hello</h1></div>
  `,
})
export class MyComponent  {
 @Input() nputmydata:mydata;
 @Output() outputmydata:mydata;
 PassData:mydata;

 constructor()
 {
    this.PassData.age='my name';
    this.PassData.data ='hello';
    this.PassData.name='rajeev';
    this._senddata(this.PassData);
 }



 private _senddata(PassData:mydata)
 {

console.log(PassData);

 }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the answer obvious?  You assign `PassData` to be `undefined` and then try to select a property of it.

Comment: even after removing undefine ...it is not working

Comment: What does "removing undefined" mean"?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Before OP edited the question, `PassData` was assigned to `undefined`

Comment: yes i removed that one but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Initialize your `PassData` field to an empty object or create a class with that type.

```
PassData:any = {};
```

2)If you want the typechecking you can make the interface parameters optional like

```
 export interface mydata
    {
    name?:string;
    age?:string;
    data?: string;
    }
```

and `PassData:mydata = {};`

3)If you want the typechecking to be strict initialize the object with empty string values,

`PassData:mydata = {name:"", age: "", data:""};`

Comment: not workng....Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'mydata'.
  Property 'name' is missing in type '{}'.

Comment: Initialise PassData with initial values for all its properties eg PassData =  {
    name : 'my name';
    age: 'age';
    data: '';
    }